# Un template para cada componente en Angular

Tags: angular, component

estoy montando una aplicación web y tengo la siguiente estructura. Tengo un fichero index.html con el siguiente código:

```
...
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
...
```

en el fichero app.component.html tengo código html donde tengo una extructura que se repite, es decir, menus, footer... y en ese mismo documento tengo la etiquete  donde me cargan los componentes.

Mi problema ahora es que tengo un componente Login donde no quiero que me herede el resto del código HTML, sino quiero que sea una página sin heredar absolamente nada, ya que es el lógin y no quiero que me carge los menús del resto de componente que forman la aplicación.

¿alguna solución?

Comment: Dónde está tu <router-outlet></router-outlet> ?.  Este es el elemento que va hacer cambiar tu pagina cuando cambies las rutas. si tus menus y tu footer se encuentran fuera de eso entonces siempre va a verse aunque cambies las rutas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa el *ngIf

```
class MyComponent {
     constructor(public router: Router) {

     }
 }


 // micomponente.component.html

 <div *ngIf="router.url !== '/route'">
     // menús
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="router.url === '/route'">
     // login
 </div>
```

Comment: Aunque esta publicación podría servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Deberías editar la respuesta un poco para añadir una descripción de lo que hace *ngIf y cómo/por qué resuelve el problema. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: No me funciona esta opción

Comment: Realicé mal la prueba, en vez de poner public router: Router, estaba probando con private router: Router, por eso no me funcionaba

Comment: Perfecto, te funcionó?